# Configuration Caching (Java / MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, caching

I have a SQL procedure that I call often (around 10-25 times a second).  The procedure itself is very well optimized, however, the pre-processing for this procedure requires a configuration based on the parameters (there are a few thousand configurations that are possible).  This configuration is stored in the database as well and changes roughly once a day to once a month.

Currently I have it set up with a cache of configurations that I use to hold configurations that have recently been used (so I don't have to query the database for the configuration every time).  The cache times out configurations after 30 minutes so if the configuration changes it will see it.

There are a couple problems with this:

1 - If the configuration changes it may take up to 30 minutes to see the change.

2 - If the configurations time out at different times on different running instances, the procedure will be run with different configurations at the same time.

So my question is:  Is there any way to do this better?   I don't want to query the database for the configuration every time but I also want to have the configuration updated as soon as it is changed.

One alternative I am considering is versioning the configuration in the database and checking the version from the database against the cache for every call.  The problem with this is that it adds another query every time I call the procedure.  I'm not sure what affect it will have on the load of the database.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

How is your cache stored?

Ideally on updating configuration, you could trigger cache clean-up.
If cache is stored in SQL as well, then you could add [TRIGGER ON UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) of your configuration table.

Comment: The cache is just stored as java objects,  they have a few strings and a couple integers.   The problem with triggers is that they cannot callback java.

Comment: Are configuration updates happening inside of this java application? If yes, you could clean up cache on the event of udating Configuration table. But my gut feeling, is that you are updating the configuration from the outside the Java application.

Comment: Alright. You can still use TRIGGER to execute external command using FUNCTION. I.e., tell the Java that cache was changed. Though I would classify involving execution of external binary as a dirty hack. On the other hand, you could have a sepparate thread checking for a cache change each few minutes. None of those are amazing solutions.